# Is there a way to test orientation changes on android service?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-orientation

setRequestedOrientation works only on activity, IWindowManager is deprecated long time ago.
Google was not much help this time.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

A Service doesn't have a graphical representation and therefore shouldn't be affected by orientation changes.

Comment: Not true. For keyboard, for example. Btw, why should orientation changes used only for gui orientation?